# Are destructors possible in Codeigniter 2.0?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Similar to building a class constructor in Codeigniter which performs a block of code before peforming other functions within a class:

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

       public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            // Your own constructor code
       }
}
?>
```

Is there a way to build a "destructor" function that properly processes a block of code after your called function is completed?  It seems that this code does not process a "footer" inside of my app:

```
function __destruct() {
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Comment: @SyntaxError: Sorry bro, I deleted it. My first few weeks on this site I wasn't so friendly.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Well that wasn't the response I was expecting! Glad to hear you've settled in since then :)

Comment: @SyntaxError: Using this site frequently has helped my patience and communication skills greatly. I'm curious: What kind of response were you expecting?

Comment: @WesleyMurch I was bracing myself for a minor argument or at least a little snark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function __destruct()`, called before object is destructed. And it isn't specific to CodeIgniter actually. Also keep in mind that if you leave your object alive to the very end of the script, so that it is destructed when PHP is shutting down there might be various problems. So if it's possible it might be a good idea to call `unset($obj)` at the end of your script.

**Update**

Now after you added what were your intentions, I can say that it won't work:). Controller is destructed when the CI superclass is being destructed, i.e. after everything was dispatched and sent to client. As a quick alternative (if it's urgent) I can suggest making action methods private to route all action requests to `__call` which will add header/footer to all your actions. But if it isn't urgent I'll make a better suggestion after I dig it a bit when I get to work...